# Copy Values to another Column in Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I have asked a question about this before, but now my situation has changed. Originally, I only needed to copy values that were either "Present" or "Absent". However, I now need to copy any integer 1-1,000.

I have tried several different variations of this code to get it to work, but I can't make the numbers fit properly.

```
function CopyCells (col) {
  var col=col || 1;
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Records');
  var rg1=sh.getRange("B2:B264");
  var vA=rg1.getValues();
  var rg2=rg1.offset(0, col);
  var vB=rg2.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    if((vA[i][0]=="Present"))||(vA[i][0]=="Absent")){
      vB[i][0]=vA[i][0];
    }
  }

  rg2.setValues(vB);

}
```

My goal is to make it where I can copy any number in B2:B264 and paste it into Column C, in the appropriate row. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function CopyCells (col) {
  var col=col || 1;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Records');
  var rg1=sh.getRange("B2:B264");
  var vA=rg1.getValues();
  var rg2=rg1.offset(0, col);
  var vB=rg2.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    if(!isNaN(vA[i][0])){
      vB[i][0]=vA[i][0];
    }
  }
  rg2.setValues(vB);
}
```

Comment: Cooper, thanks for responding so quickly. The new code you gave me works really well, but I having an issue with it. When I run it for a second time, the value that the code copied over the first time disappears, is there any way to copy the cells with just numbers, not the blank ones? Thanks for all your help! I really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the values from the source array with the JavaScript "Filter" function [1]. Using the getNextDataCell() function [2] to a Range object, you can find the last row with data in that Range, I used this to find the last row with data in column C and start to copy the data in the following row.

```
function CopyCells () {
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Records');
  var rg1=sh.getRange("B2:B264");
  var vA=rg1.getValues();

  //Filter the values to paste
  vA = vA.filter(function (value) {
    return value <= 1000 && value >= 1;
  });

  //Get the range where to paste
  var firstCell = sh.getRange("C2"); 
  if (firstCell.getValue() == "") {
    var rg2 = sh.getRange(2, 3, vA.length, 1);
  }
  else {
    var lastRow = firstCell.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getLastRow();
    var rg2 = sh.getRange(lastRow + 1, 3, vA.length, 1);
  }

  rg2.setValues(vA);
}
```

**EDIT**

To obtain the returned value of the formula you're using in column B, use the function getDisplayValues() [3] instead of getValues():

```
  var vA=rg1.getDisplayValues();
```

[1] https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getNextDataCell(Direction)

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues

Comment: Hi Andres. Thanks for your help! The problem I'm having is that when I run the code it doesn't keep the numbers in their rows. The column I'm copying from pulls from a VLOOKUP table, and I need the code to copy the returned value (Column B) from the formula into Column C. Thanks!